# Design pattern when moving repeated code out of event handlers

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I had this code:

```
Private Sub carButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles carButton.Click
    fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount("Car")
    Call updateView()
End Sub
Private Sub bicycleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bicycleButton.Click
    fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount("Bicycle")
    Call updateView()
End Sub
Private Sub lorryButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lorryButton.Click
    fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount("Lorry")
    Call updateView()
End Sub
```

I've changed it to the following:

```
Private Sub carButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles carButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(CType(sender, Button))
End Sub
Private Sub bicycleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bicycleButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(CType(sender, Button))
End Sub
Private Sub lorryButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lorryButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(CType(sender, Button))
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClickCode(ByVal mySender As Button)

    Dim incrementVehicle As String
    Select Case mySender.Name
        Case "carButton"
            incrementVehicle = "Car"
        Case "bicycleButton"
            incrementVehicle = "Bicycle"
        Case "lorryButton"
            incrementVehicle = "Lorry"
        Case Else
            incrementVehicle = ""
    End Select

    fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount(incrementVehicle)
    Call updateView()

End Sub
```

The new code has more lines of code.
Is the new version better practice, or is there a third pattern that I should be following?

---

**EDIT**

Using Guffa's answer + other comments I changed the underlying `TrafficSurveyA` model to include an enumerated Type and altered it's function `incrementCount` like so....is this enumerated type is in the correct place?

```
Enum vehicleType
    Car
    Lorry
    Bicycle
End Enum

Public Sub incrementCount(ByVal vehicle As vehicleType)
    ' Preconditions: none
    ' Postconditions: If vehicle is "Car", "Bicycle" or "Lorry" then 1 is added
    ' to the corresponding count. Otherwise nothing is done.

    Select Case vehicle
        Case vehicleType.Car : fCars = fCars + 1
        Case vehicleType.Bicycle : fBicycles = fBicycles + 1
        Case vehicleType.Lorry : fLorries = fLorries + 1
        Case Else 'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

The interface code has ended up like this:

```
Private Sub carButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles carButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(TrafficSurveyA.vehicleType.Car)
End Sub
Private Sub bicycleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bicycleButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(TrafficSurveyA.vehicleType.Bicycle)
End Sub
Private Sub lorryButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lorryButton.Click
    ButtonClickCode(TrafficSurveyA.vehicleType.Lorry)
End Sub
Private Sub ButtonClickCode(ByVal incrementVehicle As TrafficSurveyA.vehicleType)

    fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount(incrementVehicle)
    Call updateView()

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use the Name property. If someone comes along and changes the name of the control, your code breaks. Better to use `mySender` "is" { carButton | bicycleButton | lorryButton }. Then when the name is changed in Visual Studio, the code will be changed to reflect the new name.

Comment: Avoid passing strings where an enumeration can be used. Strings used this way are not type-safe and unless the person is careful cause bugs when changes are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code in the event handlers are identcal, you can have just one event handler for all the events:

```
Private Sub vehicleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles carButton.Click, bicycleButton.Click, lorryButton.Click
  Dim mySender As Button = CType(sender, Button)

  Dim incrementVehicle As String
  Select Case mySender.Name
    Case "carButton"
      incrementVehicle = "Car"
    Case "bicycleButton"
      incrementVehicle = "Bicycle"
    Case "lorryButton"
      incrementVehicle = "Lorry"
    Case Else
      incrementVehicle = ""
  End Select

  fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount(incrementVehicle)
  Call updateView()

End Sub
```

Another alternative is to keep the separate event handlers, and use the fact that each event handler can send the correct text to the common method, so you don't need to check the control name to determine the text:

```
Private Sub carButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles carButton.Click
  ButtonClickCode("Car")
End Sub

Private Sub bicycleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bicycleButton.Click
  ButtonClickCode("Bicycle")
End Sub

Private Sub lorryButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lorryButton.Click
  ButtonClickCode("Lorry")
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonClickCode(ByVal incrementVehicle As String)
  fTrafficSurveyA.incrementCount(incrementVehicle)
  Call updateView()
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend the alternative with an enum implementation. For example, `ButtonClickCode(VehicleType.Car)`.

Comment: @AMissico the `enum` implementation looks good - that is something I'll need to implement in the underlying model?

Comment: @whytheq, it depends if the enum will be used just for the presentation layer. If the enum helps with the model definiton then move into model. For instance, I once had a presentation only enum called "Node" used for determining what TreeViewItem was clicked. It became useful for other methods in the model. I refactored it into the model. Now after many more uses, it has become part of the domain model.